# Can I pass PHP variables to an external PHP file on another server

Tags: php

I have a php page where i collect php variables such as ip, host etc.  now i do this on two websites, rather than placing the information in to two seperate databases is it possible to send these php variables to my second website.

I have tried to include the file but it doesn't work, i have found tutorials but nothing i can find seems to send php variables, is this possible?, i can collect the details in javascript and pass them, but i thought php would be more accurate and collecting visitor ip addresses.

thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it's a bit unclear why you run into problems. What exactly blocks your road?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the information using HTTP GET. For example:

```
$a = 4;
header("Location: http://myothersite.com/script.php?a=$a");
```

Then, on your other website you can access that same variable using `$_GET['a']`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use XMLRPC to pass data structures along with the type information.

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php